# How to Extract a Printer or Device Icon

Tags: c#, printing, icons, device, extract

I am trying to figure out how to get the icon that is associated with an installed printer or device. For example, on Windows 7 if you goto the Devices and Printers dialog you will see a list of printers, mouses, HDDs, monitors, etc. All of these have icons assigned to them. How do I go about retrieving those icons using C#. P/Invoke is fine if I need to.

This is not duplicate of [Can I get the icon associated with an installed printer through .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680932/can-i-get-the-icon-associated-with-an-installed-printer-through-net).

Comment: I'm not sure why that question was marked as having an answer. The solution doesn't work nor does it explain how to even do it. Apparently someone was lazy.

Comment: If you still care there is answer from 2015 in liked  as duplicate that seem to answer exactly this question. (Indeed in 2012 it did not have answer to this question).

Comment: Alex, there is no answer in that question that works. Read above. DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: I thought your original comment was from 2012... Indeed it could apply to answer from 2015. Please confirm that your crystal ball was working correctly in 2012 and I'll re-open this question.

Comment: How hard is it to understand that the answer in 2012 did not work then (because it wasn't a real answer) and it's not going to magically work in 2015? Maybe you should be doing something else in your spare time?

Comment: The only reason I'm looking at this is "answer" to this question was marked for review as link only. Since I don't know history of the linked question I don't know why you believe http://stackoverflow.com/a/32852751/477420 was there in 2012 (as it is time-stamped "answered Sep 29 '15 at 19:59"). Indeed I trust you have good reasons to believe that that post in not an answer - please vote accordingly (or comment) if you find time so others know why it is not a solution.

Comment: I've also re-opened the question - if you can add reason why it is not duplicate.