# VB6 - Printers Collection in Remote Desktop Session

Tags: vb6

Does anyone know where is the file that contains all printers information the Printers Object in VB6 read from?

We usually write the coding like the following :

```
For x in **Printers** 
...  ... ...
Next
```

Normally, I would just put the list into a combo box so that users can select the printers.

When running the application at Server with the coding above for printing through remote desktop session ,I could see other's printer appear on the list too. I just want to see my own printers on the session instead of others.

In my opinion ,if i could find the location of the file, I think I could do something about it.

Any additional advice is appreciated ! :)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a file, it's an enumeration of configured devices. If you want to exclude specific printers, you can try detecting them based on the port. Arguably, this is wrong, as all configured printers are "my printers".

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code (it's a bit old now, so it propably could be done better)

Declares:

```
Public Declare Function EnumPrinters Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "EnumPrintersA" (ByVal Flags As Long, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Level As Long, ByRef pPrinterEnum As Byte, ByVal cdBuf As Long, ByRef pcbNeeded As Long, ByRef pcReturned As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

'--------------------------------------------------------------
'EnumPrinters Flags
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS As Long = &H4
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_CONTAINER   As Long = &H8000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_DEFAULT     As Long = &H1
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_EXPAND      As Long = &H4000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_FAVORITE    As Long = &H4
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_HIDE        As Long = &H1000000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON1       As Long = &H10000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON2       As Long = &H20000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON3       As Long = &H40000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON4       As Long = &H80000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON5       As Long = &H100000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON7       As Long = &H400000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON6       As Long = &H200000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICON8       As Long = &H800000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_ICONMASK    As Long = &HFF0000
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL       As Long = &H2
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_NAME        As Long = &H8
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK     As Long = &H40
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE      As Long = &H10
Public Const PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED      As Long = &H20

Public Type PRINTER_INFO_1 'REAL API STRUCTURE FOR USE WITH EnumPrinters
  Flags         As Long
  pDescription  As Long
  pName         As Long
  pComment      As Long
End Type

Public Type PRINTER_INFO_1_VB
  Flags         As Long
  pDescription  As String
  pName         As String
  pComment      As String
End Type

Private Enum NEPrinterEnumLevel1
  pel1Local = PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL
  pel1Name = PRINTER_ENUM_NAME
  pel1Default = PRINTER_ENUM_DEFAULT
  pel1Connections = PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS
  pel1Network = PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK
  pel1Remote = PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE
End Enum
```

Sub to fill a combobox:

```
'##############################################################################
'##
'##     Sub pFillcboPrinters
'##
'##############################################################################
Private Sub pFillcboPrinters()
  Dim atPIs() As PRINTER_INFO_1_VB
  Dim lCount  As Long
  Dim lIndex  As Long
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Clear List
  Call cboPrinters.Clear
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Get printers using the WinAPI
  lCount = fnEnumPrinters_PI1(atPIs(), pel1Local + pel1Connections)
  For lIndex = 1 To lCount
    Call cboPrinters.AddItem(atPIs(lIndex).pName)
  Next lIndex
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'No printers available?
  If cboPrinters.ListCount = 0 Then Call cboPrinters.AddItem("[No printers available]")
End Sub
```

The routine that actually enumerates the printers:

```
'##############################################################################
'##
'##     Function fnEnumPrinters_PI1
'##
'##############################################################################
'!! WARNING: sName = vbNullString IS IMPORTANT, BECAUSE sName = "" GIVES ANOTHER RESULT
Private Function fnEnumPrinters_PI1(ByRef atPIs() As PRINTER_INFO_1_VB, _
                                    ByVal eEnum As NEPrinterEnumLevel1, _
                                    Optional ByVal bShared As Boolean = False, _
                                    Optional ByVal sName As String = vbNullString) As Long
  Dim abBuffer()  As Byte
  Dim lBufferSize As Long
  Dim lFlags      As Long
  Dim lIndex      As Long
  Dim lLenPI1     As Long
  Dim lNeeded     As Long
  Dim lResult     As Long
  Dim lReturn     As Long
  Dim tPI1        As PRINTER_INFO_1
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Default no printers available
  lResult = 0
  ReDim atPIs(0)
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Set the flags for EnumPrinters
  lFlags = eEnum
  If bShared Then lFlags = lFlags Or PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Start with a big buffer
  lBufferSize = 32767
  lNeeded = 0
  ReDim abBuffer(lBufferSize)
  lReturn = EnumPrinters(lFlags, sName, 1, abBuffer(0), lBufferSize, lNeeded, lResult)
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Need a bigger buffer? try again with bigger buffer
  If (lReturn = 0) And (lNeeded > 0) Then
    ReDim abBuffer(lBufferSize)
    lReturn = EnumPrinters(lFlags, sName, 1, abBuffer(0), lBufferSize, lNeeded, lResult)
  End If 'If (lReturn=0) And (lNeeded>0)
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Everything OK? and printers to retrieve?
  If (lReturn <> 0) And (lResult > 0) Then
    '--------------------------------------------------------------
    'Create enough entries for the Printerinfo's
    ReDim atPIs(lResult)
    lLenPI1 = Len(tPI1)
    '--------------------------------------------------------------
    'Buffer constist of first all PRINTER_INFO_1 and after that extra info,
    'but the PRINTER_INFO_1 contains the important information which get's
    'the other information, but we only use the PRINTER_INFO_1 info of the buffer
    For lIndex = 1 To lResult
      '--------------------------------------------------------------
      'Copy the info to the real API PRINTER_INFO_1
      Call MoveMemory(tPI1, abBuffer((lIndex - 1) * lLenPI1), lLenPI1)
      '--------------------------------------------------------------
      'Copy the information to the VB version
      With atPIs(lIndex)
        '--------------------------------------------------------------
        'Copy the flags
        .Flags = tPI1.Flags
        '--------------------------------------------------------------
        'Copy the Description
        .pDescription = Space$(lstrlen(tPI1.pDescription))
        Call lstrcpy(.pDescription, tPI1.pDescription)
        '--------------------------------------------------------------
        'Copy the name
        .pName = Space$(lstrlen(tPI1.pName))
        Call lstrcpy(.pName, tPI1.pName)
        '--------------------------------------------------------------
        'Copy the Comment
        .pComment = Space$(lstrlen(tPI1.pComment))
        Call lstrcpy(.pDescription, tPI1.pComment)
      End With 'With atPIs(lIndex)
    Next lIndex
  End If 'If (lReturn<>0) And (lResult>0)
  '--------------------------------------------------------------
  'Return the ammount of printers
  fnEnumPrinters_PI1 = lResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063874/retrieving-icons-of-current-user-printers) to enum explorer Printers Folder in a combobox and show their icons too. Works under RDS too.